# Не видны .png на странице

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 5]
[image: 4]
в вёрсте в sublime всё работает как надо (последний скрин)

Пытался менять структуру папок, изменял исходный размер .png картинок

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Riblick</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Riblick</name>
    <description>Riblick</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Если используется Spring Security. то это может быть причиной. Надо разрешить доступ к папке с картинками всем (добавить в исключения spring security)

Comment: Я не использовал базу данных в проекте, все картинки п т.п добавлял напрямую через папку

Comment: Это не база данных, это модуль отвечающий за безопасность в spring приложениях. Добавьте pom.xml или gradle в вопрос.

Comment: добавил pom файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, данная проблема вызвана тем, что модуль Spring Security не сконфигурирован. Компоненты Spring Security включены в spring-boot-starter-web. Добавьте в проект файл конфигурации, например

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/images/**")
            .antMatchers("/js/**")
            .antMatchers("/css/**");
    }
}
```

где web.ignoring() содержит пути до папки картинок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил файл конфигурации и указал пути web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**").antMatchers("/logo/**"); , но png и css перестают подключаться (чистый html, картинки также не отображаются), после добавления в pom файл (spring-boot-starter-security). Изменял пути к файлу css в html на: th:href="@{/css/reset.css} (ранее указывал href="/css_main.css"). Но результата не получил.